# How to Set QPixmap from Bytes in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, byte, qpixmap

How to set Pixmap of label from a bytes of an images file `("example.bmp")`. I have searched and tried every way almost all day, but I can't find a solution.

I want to set the Pixmap of a label to display the image from the "**Bytes**" source, but I don't want to save the image file on disk. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Or maybe is there a way how to save the sequence of bytes into a file `example2.bmp` in memory (buffer or _io.BufferedReader)?

Here is my code

```
with open("example.bmp", 'rb') as file:
    header = file.read(53)
    pixeldata = file.read()

images = header+pixel #Bytes sequence of example.bmp file
pixmap = QPixmap.loadFromData(images)
self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Comment: [`loadFromData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#loadFromData) does not return the pixmap, it returns a bool reporting if the image was correctly loaded. Create a QPixmap instance, *then* call `loadFromData()`.

Comment: I can't believe that I actually found the solution in other people's code before asking here, but at that time, I didn't realize that. I have to say, really thanks for reminding me @musicamante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found solution from my mistakes. Thanks to @musicamante for reminding me.

```
with open("example.bmp", 'rb') as file:
    header = file.read(53)
    pixeldata = file.read()

images = header+pixel #Bytes sequence of example.bmp file

# Create QPixmap instance
pixmap = QPixmap()

# Put bytes of example.bmp into it
pixmap.loadFromData(images)

# Apply that to the label
self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```